# Trying to add H1 to Wordpress Blog Post (main page that displays blog post)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add an H1 to my Wordpress Blog Page (main page that displays all blog post) but any changes I make in the wp-admin > page > page elements section of the page are not being recognised. Where can I find the script so that I can add the code to show an h1 title.

Many thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks Jasbir. That did not work but I have now fixed the problem. I needed to locate the index.php file and added h1 tags to the dynamic page titles.

Answer (score 0):

May be I am not confirm, But you can check the `content.php` in your active theme where you will find the blog post title between `<header class="entry-header"></header>`